Missing M.2 screw that I can't identify for MSI MPG B550 Gaming Plus"
I just received a second M.2 SSD that I'm trying to install, but the screw wasn't included in the box and isn't in my motherboard's box. It doesn't help that it looks like an uncommon screw type

Where can I find a replacement for this kind of screw? Does this have a name?

The only way to 100% sure, since these screws are not always standard, is to check the motherboard's manual or with MSI support

That looks like a case side-panel thumb screw, not a motherboard screw.

@spikey_richie It's a thumbscrew with an M2 threaded hole. It can be moved to the other locations on the motherboard to account for different sizes of SSD, as shown in Florian Castellane's answer.

According to the manual: https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/MPG-B550-GAMING-PLUS/support#manual
The size of the screws is not specified, but they are supposed to be included with the motherboard.

The screws themselves being usually sold with matching standoffs, you could get a set of both and replace the original standoffs if they don't fit the original screws.

